# Silberschatz atomic increment clarification

Tags: c, concurrency, atomic, compare-and-swap

The Silberschatz implementation of the compare and swap function is the following

```
int compare_and_swap(int *value, int expected, int new_value) {
    int temp = *value;
    if (*value == expected)
        *value = new_value;
    return temp;
}
```

it can be used to implement an atomic increment function

```
void increment(atomic_int *v)
{
    int temp;
    do {
        temp = *v;
    }
    while (temp != compare_and_swap(v, temp, temp+1));
}
```

my question is: under what circumstances the do-while condition is true to trigger a second cycle and thus a second `compare_and_swap` invocation?

From my understanding the `compare_and_swap`always returns the old `v` but, before calling it the `temp` value is initialized with the `v` value and so the `compare_and_swap` returns `temp` in the first place and the condition than fails causing the exit from the cycle.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `increment` function implementation, the test condition for do-while loop will fail if the increment operation has been successful.

So, your understanding that `compare_and_swap` function always returns the same variable is absolutely correct, given the function executed without any interruptions.

But with multiple threads trying to access the same variable, this might not be the case. And under those scenarios, we get the test condition for do-while loop to be true, hence attempt to increment the variable in second cycle, and so on.

E.g: Suppose there are two threads writing to the same variable `v=0`.
The first thread is executing the `increment` function, and gets interrupted just after the instruction `temp = *v;`. After this, the second thread is given the control and it completes the increment function and after that only the control is returned to thread 1.

So, under this situation, as the control returns, following is the status of the variables:

```
v = 1 \\ Got incremented after the thread-2 execution completed
temp = 0 \\ Was set before thread-1 was interrupted
```

So now, when the while test condition executes, `compare_and_swap` returns 1, but `temp` is 0. Hence the test fails and the loop body is re-executed.

Comment: So, the reason that the loop body is re-executed is to reflect updates by another threads to the shared variable? — If there is no loop, the `temp` is still zero, so the result value would be incremented by one only, ignoring updates by another threads.